# Null reference when passing an array to a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, unit-testing

I get the following error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

When I try to run this unit test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestDecreaseTutorArea()
    {
        HelpWith info = new HelpWith();
        info.Subcategories[0] = 1;
        info.UserId = 14;

        TutorService tutorService = new TutorService();

        tutorService.DecreaseTutorArea(info);
    }
```

The `HelpWith` class looks like this:

```
public class HelpWith
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int[] Categories { get; set; }
    public int[] Subcategories { get; set; }
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Seems to me like I made it very clear what `info-Subcategories` is.

Comment: What does the `HelpWith` constructor look like?

Comment: adding exceptionhandling should help you. Now it looks like the construction of the object fails. I do not write in C#, but I wonder if get; and set; are two valid integers. If not, then might the construction of the object fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't initialized your arrays to any size. And you are trying to access the element

```
 info.Subcategories[0] = 1;
```

That is why you are getting the exception.

Initialize them to some size before using or in constructor.

```
public void TestDecreaseTutorArea()
    {
        HelpWith info = new HelpWith();
        info.SubCategories = new int[10]; //here
        info.Subcategories[0] = 1;
        info.UserId = 14;

        TutorService tutorService = new TutorService();

        tutorService.DecreaseTutorArea(info);
    }
```

Or in the class constructor:

```
public class HelpWith
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int[] Categories { get; set; }
    public int[] Subcategories { get; set; }
    //constructor
    public HelpWith()
    {
      this(10,10);
    }

    public HelpWith(int CategorySize, int SubCategorySize)
    {
     Categories = new int[CategorySize]; //some size
     SubCategories = new int[SubCategorySize];
    }
}
```

If you don't know the size of the array before hand then use `List<int>`, but remember to initialize it in constructor like:

```
public class HelpWith
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public List<int> Categories { get; set; }
    public List<int> Subcategories { get; set; }
    //constructor
    public HelpWith()
    {
        Categories = new List<int>();
        Subcategories = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

Then for using it:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestDecreaseTutorArea()
{
    HelpWith info = new HelpWith();
    info.Subcategories.Add(1);
    info.UserId = 14;

    TutorService tutorService = new TutorService();

    tutorService.DecreaseTutorArea(info);
}
```

Comment: Oh... You're right!
Hmm.. That poses the problem that I cannot know its size beforehand...
I've changed the Public int[] Subcategories to
public List<int> Subcategories (As far as I know, lists don't need a specific length), but I still get the same error...
Even if I also change info.Subcategories[0] = 1; to info.Subcategories.Add(1);

Comment: @user2392980, then use `List<int>` instead of Array

Comment: I have, I just hit enter too soon, when writing the response :P

Comment: @user2392980, again initialize the list in constructor, see the updated answer

Comment: After having reloaded the page, I saw your update answer. It works now, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The error happens here

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestDecreaseTutorArea()
{
    HelpWith info = new HelpWith();
    info.Subcategories[0] = 1; <<<<<<<<
}
```

Because the `info.Subcategories` is `null`. To fix this add a constructor with something like

```
public class HelpWith
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int[] Categories { get; set; }
    public int[] Subcategories { get; set; }

    HelpWith()
    {
        Categories = new int[5];
        Subcategories = new int[5];
    }
}
```

And you would probably want to use a `List<int>` instead of the `int[]` as the list is a dynamic array, it can grow and shrink in size (meaning you don't have to provide the initial size, as you need to do with the `int[]`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the arrays - either in a constructor or after creating the object:

```
    HelpWith info = new HelpWith();
    info.Subcategories = new int[20];
    info.Subcategories[0] = 1;
    info.UserId = 14;
```

How else is the system meant to know how large these arrays should be?

(Alternatively, consider using a different data type, such as [`List<int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), if you don't want to manage the length of the arrays - but you still need to initialize them)